Condition for vehicle jump
Consider a small body moving on a curved surface under influence of the homogeneous gravitational field $\vec g$. This represents a rolling ball with a negligible momentum of inertia, a bike or a car coasting in neutral on a road. I wonder how to predict if and where the body detaches from the surface, i.e. what is the general condition for a jump.
I'm aware of a similar exercise in which a small ball rolls from the top of a large ball, solution of which relies on these two steps:


As long as the ball touches the other, you one can use the energy conservation to find its actual velocity as follows: $v^2 = v_0^2 + g \,\Delta h= v_0^2 + g R (1-\sin\phi)$, where $v_0$ is the initial velocity of the small ball at the top.
As long as the ball touches the surface of the other, there are two forces acting on it in the direction perpendicular to its velocity: the projection of the gravity ($F_1 = F_g \sin\phi$) and the mechanical pressure force between the two balls ($F_r$), magnitude of which adjusts just to keep the small ball out of the volume of the large (rigid) body, which leads us to:
$F_1 - F_r = F_\rm{centripetal}$, i.e. $g \sin\phi - F_r/m = v^2/R$. As $F_r$ must  point outwards ($F_r\geq 0$), it can't prevent the small ball to fly out of the large one, and so the detaching moment is when $F_r=0$, i.e. \begin{equation}v^2/g = R \sin\phi\,,\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(1)\end{equation} which can be easily solved for $\phi$.

I would like to generalize this solution to any smooth surface. For simplicity, we can stick in a 2D world where the surface (road) is described as a function $y(x)$. It is straightforward to generalize the 1st step above to something like
$v(x)^2 = v(x_0)^2 + g \left(y(x_0) - y(x)\right)$,
but interpreting $R$ and $\sin\phi$ from Eq. (1) in the second paragraph is not.
So my questions are:

How to generalize the above condition from a situation with circular surface to other cases?
Is there a way of deriving the desired general solution without viewing it as a generalization of the above situation?


Your condition $F_r = 0$ seems correct to me. I believe your equation (1) is already a generalization in that you don't need to restrict the motion to be on a circle.  Just say R is the instantaneous radius of curvature of any smooth surface at the contact point.

Given a function $y(x)$, how to calculate $R(x)$ and $\sin\phi(x)$?

The wikipedia page on radius of curvature has an answer for your first question.  As to the second, I think you can calculate this based on the slope $dy/dx$.  Note that you need to be a little careful with signs; it's possible for the curve to be convex OR concave but $R$ would have the same absolute value in either case.
